# JavaScript is not indented Firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

My JavaScript is perfectly indented in Eclipse, but when I debug the same JavaScript code in Firebug it is not. Not sure why and it makes it much harder to debug. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you show a sample and specify how do you launch the test from Eclipse?

Comment: insert the images which shows the issue please.

Comment: Are you using a minifier or anything?

Comment: are you using tabs or spaces for indenting in your editor? (or possibly mixing the two...?? that would definitely make things go wrong when viewed in other programs)

Answer (score 1):

Things I can think of that could cause this are:

- A minifier on the server side
- The internet provider minifying the response to save bandwidth (e.g. for UMTS connections)
- A bad setting for [`extensions.firebug.replaceTabs`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Preferences) (like e.g. 0 or 1)
- A bug in Firebug

I'd guess it's one of the first two.

Sebastian